# Certain data types won't save in My.Settings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, application-settings

I've had issues getting custom objects, `System.Object`, and `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` to save in `My.Settings`. These are all objects not listed in the drop down menu or by hitting browse. Any other predefined object works great.

Comment: They arent listed because they are not supported

Comment: Are you saying that by assumption or somewhere it's actually listed? I've searched and searched and found quite little on it.

Comment: Serializing means saving the properties of the thing to some notation from which it can be recreated.  Whatever you put in `Object` will loose all the specific properties it has because those are not defined for `Object`.  Same with that awful VB Collection because it can only store `Object` vs concrete types.

Comment: Yes, but I never mentioned serialization. Based on what you said, I assume that's what happens when you save settings?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up serializing to solve my problem. I went Object to Byte Array, and then Byte Array to String. Simply reverse when you want to pull the settings. Remember to mark classes as Serializable.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

Module SettingsSerialization
    Public Function ObjectToByteArray(ByVal Obj As Object) As Byte()
        Dim bf As BinaryFormatter = New BinaryFormatter()
        Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            bf.Serialize(ms, Obj)
            Return ms.ToArray()
        End Using
    End Function

Public Function ByteArrayToString(ByVal ByteArray As Byte()) As String
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(ByteArray)
End Function

Public Function StringToByteArray(ByVal Str As String) As Byte()
    Return Convert.FromBase64String(Str)
End Function

Public Function ByteArrayToObject(ByVal ByteArray As Byte()) As Object
        Dim bf As BinaryFormatter = New BinaryFormatter
        Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
            ms.Write(ByteArray, 0, ByteArray.Length)
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            Return bf.Deserialize(ms)
        End Using
    End Function
End Module
```

Example usage:

```
'Getting the setting.
Dim myclass As CustomClass = SettingsSerialization.ByteArrayToObject(SettingsSerialization.StringToByteArray(My.Settings.CustomClass))

'Properly setting and saving.
My.Settings.CustomClass = SettingsSerialization.ByteArrayToString(SettingsSerialization.ObjectToByteArray(CustomClass))
My.Settings.Save()
```

Comment: a) If you use the BF why pass/serialize as `Object` when you could use the actual type? b) since the result is binary, rather than ASCII encoding a Base64 string would be a better choice (or rather than a memstream just write it to disk yourself).

Comment: Because then I'd be limited to serializing just that type. I'd like to be able to pass any object, otherwise I have to overload the functions. Besides, when I retrieve my object, I create an instance of it anyway. Updated my answer with Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

`I'd like to be able to pass any object, otherwise I have to overload the functions.`

Generics mean never having to box things `As Object`:

```
Private Function SerializeToB64(Of T)(item As T) As String

    Using ms As New MemoryStream
        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        bf.Serialize(ms, item)
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
    End Using
End Function

Private Function DeSerializeFromB64(Of T)(data As String) As T

    Using ms As New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(data))
        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        ' serializer creates the new object
        Dim newT As T = CType(bf.Deserialize(ms), T)
        Return newT
    End Using

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim A As New Animal With {.Name = "Gizmo", .Species = "Mugwai"}

Dim b64 = SerializeToB64(A)

Dim A2 = DeSerializeFromB64(Of Animal)(b64)
Console.WriteLine("Animal name: {0}, species: {1}", A2.Name, A2.Species)
```

---

If there are several objects to be saved, you can create a "Mailer" of sorts to hold all the objects, and serialize them all at once:

```
<Serializable>
Public Class SerializingMailer
    Public Property AnimalItem As Animal
    Public Property FooItem As Foo
    Public Property BarItem As Bar

    ' some serializers require a simple ctor
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Note that rather than feeding a B64 string back to `My.Settings`, you could just save them to disk yourself by using a `FileStream`.

Comment: I don't entirely see the difference between our methods. They both seem to have the same outcome. Object seems to be generic enough. Writing to disk means less portability. I'm writing to Settings so I can avoid writing to disk.

Comment: They are actually different when deserializing.  Using a generic, the returned type is correct (`Animal`, `Employee` whatever).  The only way to get at `Animal` properties on an `Object` is to cast the return or use late binding (which in turn means Option Strict is Off).  `As Object` is not desirable,